# How contact Column table in T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql

This is   my table user I want a contact column in one record
I am usinng this query but it dont work, seprate colume with ',' 
please help me.

```
   id        CourseName 
    1          ali
    2          saeed
    3          amir
  i want this result
    CourseName 
   ali,saeed,amir

DECLARE @coursename nvarchar(200)
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
       DECLARE @Temp TABLE (  CourseName NVARCHAR(500)  )
             Insert INTO @Temp      
                 select [dbo].Course_Get_Name(Course_ID) as Coursename  
                            from TLab_CourseUsingLab
                                          where Lab_ID=@labid
              declare @count int
              select  @count=   count(*) from @Temp
                    WHILE ( (@count) > 0)
                    BEGIN
                          select @coursename=  CourseName from @Temp
                             set  @coursename = @coursename+ ','
                             set  @count=@count-1
                    End 

-- select   CourseName from @Temp
END
```

Comment: Could you be more specific how it does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some messed up code. Try this:

```
SELECT  STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + c.CourseName
                FROM    TLab_CourseUsingLabl l
                        JOIN CorseNames c ON l.Course_ID = c.Course_ID
                WHERE   l.Lab_ID = @labid
                FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 1, '')
```

Comment: WATHS JOIN CorseNames c

Comment: It is the table where you keep course names `id        CourseName 
    1          ali
    2          saeed
    3          amir`

Comment: thanks  .
Please explain whats number  , 1, 1, ''  in FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 1, '')

Comment: Those numbers are from the STUFF function. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx

Comment: you are concatenating strings `',' + c.CourseName` in the end you get extra comma in beginnung: `,ali,saeed,amir`. STUFF function go to position 1 in the resulting string and gets substring of length 1 and replaces it with ''. You are just removing first extra comma